# Count Matching Character Array Values Going Backwards Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to count how many values are in the same spot in Java going backwards in an array comparing between two arrays. So for example cat and bat would count 2. So, finding the values matching going backwards in an array starting on the right to left. I want to increase the score every time a match is made.

I have tried this and it is not working.

```
for(int counter = Array1.length - 1; counter <= 0; counter--){
    if (Array1[counter] == Array2[counter]) {
        backwardsScore++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change to `counter >= 0`

Comment: I tried that. The code still seems not to be counting correctly. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is the data type of the items of the array?

Comment: It is a character array. I broke the word up into characters.

Comment: If you did it with `toCharArray()` then the code with `>= 0` should be working. Of course before the loop there must be this line: `int backwardsScore = 0;` right?

Comment: Yes I have that. I think I have it working now. It seems when word 1st array is bigger than the second it gives this error. java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your code works only for equal sized arrays.

Comment: Do you know how to get it to work for any size arrays to be compared?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0):

First fix the loop to be counter >= 0 since you are counting down, then use <s>Array1[counter].equals(Array2[counter]) so that you are testing whether the values are equal.</s>

Use Math.min(Array1.length, Array2.length) as the loop initial value.

To see what's actually being compared, add the following before your if:
`System.out.printf("%c %c", Array1[counter], Array2[counter]);`

and `System.out.println("Found Match!");` inside the if block

Comment: I did those things. I have it as a character array so I don't think I can do equals. Also, it gives an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when the first array is bigger. Do you know a fix for this?

Comment: You would need to do a Math.min(Array1.length, Array2.length) as your starting value.  How are your arrays declared (please show the declaration)?  an ArrayList of Chars is different than a char[].  If you are using a collection which uses Objects not primitives, then you definitely need to use .equals

Comment: Try adding `System.out.printf("%c %c", Array1[counter], Array2[counter]);` right before your if statement and see what is actually being compared.

Comment: I tried adding that and it just spits out jibberish into the console

Comment: Add `System.out.printf("%s %s", entry1, entry2)` before you do the .toCharAway - what do the strings look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] arr1 = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
        char[] arr2 = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd' };

        int len = (arr1.length >= arr2.length) ? arr2.length : arr1.length;
        int backwardsScore = 0;
        for (int index = len - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            if (arr1[index] == arr2[index]) {
                backwardsScore++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(backwardsScore);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have it as a character array, so I don't think the equals works for it.

Comment: I updated the answer and provided a code snippet that works. Let me know for what use-case is your code failing still.

Answer (score 0):

For any size arrays:

```
int min = Array1.length;
if (Array2.length < min) then
    min = Array2.length;
for(int counter = min - 1; counter >= 0; counter--){
    if (Array1[counter] == Array2[counter]) {
        backwardsScore++;
    }
}
```

This will start from the last index of the smallest array.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
    String[] a1 = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
    String[] a2 =     {"b","a","d","e"};

    int time = Math.min(a1.length,a2.length);
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= time; i++){
        if(a1[a1.length-i] == a2[a2.length-i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```